# JQuery need to clear a text box when clicking calendar button

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have a textbox with calendar button. Here my requirement is I need to clear the text box when user clicks Calendar Image control. Please provide JQuery for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can I finish my sandwich first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the simple answer is:

```
$("#calendarButton").click(function(){    
   $("#yourTextBoxId").val('');
});
```

But if you want a more detailed solution I would suggest you post some sample code.